# OpenCV 2.4.9: program not running in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

I have a very strange issue with openCV.
After a long struggle to get all libraries linked and all, I finnaly thought I got openCV to work with Eclipse.

So, I opened up a new project and pasted in an example program, taken from openCV's website.
I build and run the program, but it just terminates. Even the print statement won't execute.

Only after commenting out all openCV related code, my print statement will execute..

I debugged the program, but everything seems to be working fine.

My testprogram:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void createAlphaMat(Mat &mat)
{
    CV_Assert(mat.channels() == 4);
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat.cols; ++j) {
            Vec4b& bgra = mat.at<Vec4b>(i, j);
            bgra[0] = UCHAR_MAX; // Blue
            bgra[1] = saturate_cast<uchar>((float (mat.cols - j)) / ((float)mat.cols) * UCHAR_MAX); // Green
            bgra[2] = saturate_cast<uchar>((float (mat.rows - i)) / ((float)mat.rows) * UCHAR_MAX); // Red
            bgra[3] = saturate_cast<uchar>(0.5 * (bgra[1] + bgra[2])); // Alpha
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl;

    // Create mat with alpha channel
    Mat mat(480, 640, CV_8UC4);
    createAlphaMat(mat);

    vector<int> compression_params;
    compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION);
    compression_params.push_back(9);

    try {
        imwrite("alpha.png", mat, compression_params);
    }
    catch (runtime_error& ex) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Exception converting image to PNG format: %s\n", ex.what());
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Steps I took to get this thing semi-working:

1. Download and built openCV with CMake
2. Create a new C++ project in Eclipse
3. Add openCV build folder to GCC C++ compiler
4. Add custom build folder for mingw to Library search path (-L)
5. Add libraries (-l)
6. Build project and run it

At first I would get missing references to the libraries because mingw needs a custom build to work with Eclipse. So that's what I did.

I had a similar issue when my antivirus program was running, so I disabled it.

Now the strange thing is:

This won't work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void createAlphaMat(Mat &mat)
{
    CV_Assert(mat.channels() == 4);
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat.cols; ++j) {
            Vec4b& bgra = mat.at<Vec4b>(i, j);
            bgra[0] = UCHAR_MAX; // Blue
            bgra[1] = saturate_cast<uchar>((float (mat.cols - j)) / ((float)mat.cols) * UCHAR_MAX); // Green
            bgra[2] = saturate_cast<uchar>((float (mat.rows - i)) / ((float)mat.rows) * UCHAR_MAX); // Red
            bgra[3] = saturate_cast<uchar>(0.5 * (bgra[1] + bgra[2])); // Alpha
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But this will:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

What the hell?

**EDIT: DEBUGGER OUPUT**

- The target endianness is set automatically (currently little endian)
- [New Thread 13932.0x155c]
- [New Thread 13932.0x3730]
- [New Thread 13932.0x31a0]
- [New Thread 13932.0x2e84]
- [Thread 13932.0x2e84 exited with code 3221225781]
- [Thread 13932.0x31a0 exited with code 3221225781]

Comment: When you run your code from the 1st example in the debugger, where does it stall? Might have something to do with loading of shared libraries needed by OpenCV, that cannot be found or such.

Comment: It seems like it doesn't stall, but just finishes, I added the debugger output in my post.